# Datatable checkbox selection setting null

Tags: jsf-2, checkbox, primefaces, datatable

I have included in the dataTable  `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%"/>` and given a array to dataTable `selection="#{login.selectedAlarms}"` but while am selecting the checkBoxs its not setting anything to array. While selecting all checkBox's also array is null.

```
<p:dataTable id="eventsDataTable" value="#{login.lstAlaramDataByType}" 
             selection="#{login.selectedAlarms}"
             rowKey="#{item.id}" var="item" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%"/>

    <p:column id="vehicleId" headerText="vehicleId" width="60">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.vehicleId}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Java Code:

```
private List<AlarmDataBean> lstAlaramDataByType;
private AlarmDataBean[] selectedAlarms;
```

and Setters and getters for them.

`setSelectedAlarms` 
not getting called while selecting checkBox.

Am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Can you post `login` bean which has above methods?

Comment: To avoid the obvious, are you submitting the form after you selected the checkboxes? Or are you really only paying attention to the setter instead of the real action/listener method? Getters/setters should be your least concern.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see a call to your setSelectedAlarms(), you need to submit the form (e.g. via a button), or alternatively add an ajax event, like so:

```
<p:datatable ...>
  <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"/>
  ...
</p:dataTable>
```